# What is the meaning of the fat arrow syntax when being passed as a parameter in a function call?

Tags: lambda, typescript, angular

I'm looking at the following code, from [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.0)

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
@Injectable()
export class AddressBookService {
    http:Http;
    constructor(http:Http){
        console.log('Creating AddressBookService');
        this.http = http;
    }
    getEntries(){
        return this.http.get('./people.json').map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding what the meaning of `res => res.json()` is. I thought it must be a lambda function, but I don't understand what the point of it is. It's not returning and storing a variable or performing any useful operations it seems.

It would be great if someone could explain what this does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this line:

```
return this.http.get('./people.json').map(res => res.json());
```

as this snippet:

```
function myMap(res) {
    return res.json();
}

var res = this.http.get('./people.json');
return myMap(res);
```

Comment: `map` iterates over elements so it would be more like `var result=[];for(var i=0;i<res.length; i++){ result.push(res[i].json());} return result;` but it might not be an actual array either just some collection that is iterable by the method.

Comment: Yes I know. But according to the given snippet, `res` is not actually an array. So, to clarify, I decide to ignore the array part ;) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

```
return this.http.get('./people.json').map(res => res.json());
```

Is [ES6 syntax sugar](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) and in this case it's identical in functionality with this ES5 compatible version:

```
return this.http.get('./people.json').map(function(res) {return  res.json();});
```

The name `map` and it's use in the code indicates that `this.http.get('./people.json')` would be some sort of collection and that `map` iterates each of the elements making a new collection out of the result of doing the function on every one of the elements. It should behave similar as [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
[1,2,3,4].map(x => x+1); // ==> [2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

`this` is bound to the scope where the function is defined (the current `AddressBookService` instance. Because the function doesn't use `this` it doesn't matter if you use `=>` or `function () ...` but it also doesn't hurt to use `=>` everywhere because it's less error prone if you actually use `this`.